# beanstalkd c client library

Tags: c, api, client, message-queue, beanstalkd

We are going to implement a fairly complex new service in an asynchronous way, introducing asynchronous processing as well. For this, we have selected [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) message queue service, as it fits best for our needs.

The problem is that beanstalk seems to miss client API in C, at least I have failed to find it.

I do not want to invent the wheel: is there a client API available for beanstalkd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[libbeanstalkd](http://github.com/bergundy/libbeanstalkclient) also has some commits lately..

Wondering why you want client also in C. Are you going to program client in such a low level language? btw [gearmand](http://gearman.org/index.php?id=download) has a c client library. Maybe you could consider that instead

Comment: it's only a skeleton, seems to be a good, coherent start, but it's far from being ready and useful. sorry, but the question is still open

Comment: gearmand does not fit the requirements - we look for a message queue, not a distributed workload system

Comment: What is the difference? I believe they both are the same, but the description is just a little bit different?

Comment: I am looking for message queuing, not job distribution system... bearmand looks like a patchwork without real scope and roboust design, beanstalkd has a clean, nice design and meant to be a message queue I am looking for. please rewrite your answer to refer to libbeanstalkclient and I am going to accept it, because libbeanstalkclient is now ready to be used.

Comment: and C support (as well as PHP and java) is chosen because the system is going to be quite complex and heavy loaded. In order to implement it fast, we are going to develop a complete signaling network (libbeanstalkd or other MQ steps in) and divide the 'work' into small jobs connected by MQ. The jobs are going to be implemented in PHP, but we reserve the way of re-implementing the jobs in other programming languages like C, in order to gain performance. That is something gearmand cannot do.